# Client Side Composing | Create Elements vs. .innerHTML writes | invisible code

Tags: php, javascript, html, json, structured-data

Which is better?

Is there a way to keep content out of the view->source()?

Comment: If you want it to render in the browser, there's no way to completely keep it from showing in the source.  Users with firebug, or even the base functionality in Chrome show even AJAX loaded content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what they objected to was the use off innerHTML. Some would say that constructing and adding nodes (http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodes_add.asp) would be the more refined way to do this and you should at least look at it as an option.  If it's too much work, I say just go with innerHTML.  It's supported by pretty much any browser anyway. (http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html)

Comment: As best I understand it, the issue isn't environment as much as the quantity of data you're dealing with.  If you have a really deep DOM tree, having the DOM read into memory will cause it to take longer.  If it's a relatively small tree, adding via DOM is more efficient.  Most of all, the using the DOM is often considered "more correct" because it forces you to model all the stuff you're adding in before you add it, where you could add 50 more nodes using the innerHTML method and then you have a harder time modifying again later.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm referring to.